# select max from a count in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have :

```
SELECT
    "Month",
    COUNT( Trip_Id ) AS 'Number of Trips'
FROM
    Tor_Bikes AS tb 
GROUP BY
    "Month";
```

Which gives me a table of each month with its number of trips for that month. I need the month that has the most number of trips. How do I do this?

Comment: See [SQLite LIMIT and ORDER BY clause](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-limit/)

Comment: I'm new to SQL, correct me if i'm wrong but i think the order by function could give the same result... just with other unwanted results but at least its what you see first :) Order by the count of Trip ID in descending order after grouping by month..

Answer (score 2):

#### WARNING: UNTESTED

I'm learning SQL myself, so this is by no means canonical, and there may be mistakes. We all know how to produce such a table:

```
(SELECT `productID`, count(`productID`) AS `TotalPriceChanges` FROM `ProductCostHistory` GROUP BY `productID`) 

ProductID       Count(*)
    '707'     | '3'
    '708'     | '3'
    '709'     | '1'
    '710'     | '1'
    '711'     | '3'
```

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to select the Max value of THIS table. Well, you can simply use the above as a derived table - sub query or CTE (Common Table Expression). Using MYSQL it would be something like this:

```
Select ProductID, max(TotalPriceChanges) FROM
          (SELECT `productID`, count(`productID`) AS `TotalPriceChanges` FROM `ProductCostHistory` GROUP BY `productID`) as derivedTable
Group by `ProductID`
```

We use an alias `as` to name the derived table, and instead of using the aggregative function `count` we use the function `max`. The above works for me.

#### Final Solution

```
SELECT Month, Max('Number of Trips') FROM
    (
        SELECT
        "Month",
        COUNT( Trip_Id ) AS 'Number of Trips'
    FROM
        Tor_Bikes AS tb 
    GROUP BY
        "Month"  AS DerivedTable;
    )
GROUP BY MONTH
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use subqueries to achieve that:

```
SELECT MAX(Number_of_Trips) FROM (SELECT "Month", Count( Trip_Id ) FROM
    Tor_Bikes AS tb 
GROUP BY
    "Month";)
```

Comment: You have the right idea but the SQL is invalid, don't forget to alias the `count` `count(Trip_Id) Number_of_Trips`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query you are searching for:

```
SELECT      Month, Max('Number of Trips') 
FROM
    (
      SELECT    Month, COUNT( Trip_Id ) AS 'Number of Trips'
      FROM      Trips AS tb 
      GROUP BY  Month
    )
```